# Unable to find Xcode project file while Compiling with Apportable

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, cross-compiling, apportable

I download Cocos2DSimpleGame from Apportable Sample app page.when i am trying to compile through CLI it says

```
 mac6:Cocos2DSimpleGame Stalin$ apportable load
Building with TARGET_ARCH_ABI:armeabi ARM_NEON:False
Building to /Users/Stalin/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug
Error: Unable to find Xcode project file. /Applications/Cocos2DSimpleGame3-master/Cocos2DSimpleGame
```

Answer (score 0):

`apportable load` should be run from the same directory that include the .xcodeproj file for the iOS version of the project.